# Number of trials nesessary to determine probability with given credibility

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I have the following problem,
"A web page contained a link with CTR=1.5%. The link has been modified: now it appears in 4% of all page shows.
What number of impressions of the page do we need to determine the new CTR within 95% accuracy? Why?"

I've used the integral theorem of de Moivre-Laplace to calculate relative frequency deviation from constant probability:
$P(|\frac{m}{n}-p|\leq \varepsilon)=2\Phi (\varepsilon \sqrt{\frac{n}{pq}})$, where $m$ - number of clicks on the link, $n$ - shows of this link on page,
$\varepsilon$ - deviation, $p$ - probability of click, when the page contain the link (new CTR), $\Phi$ - Laplace function.
By the conditions of the problem 
$P(|\frac{m}{n}-p|\leq \varepsilon)=0.95$. 
Therefore 
$2\Phi (\varepsilon \sqrt{\frac{n}{pq}})=\frac{0.95}{2}=0.475$
or 
$\varepsilon \sqrt{\frac{n}{pq}}=\varepsilon \sqrt{\frac{n}{p(1-p)}}=1.96$.
We don't know new CTR, but we can find the maximum of $p(1-p)$ function: it is equal to $0.25$ for $p$ in $[0;1]$.
Thus $n=\frac{1.96*0.25}{\varepsilon^{2}}$.

And now I'm stuck.
Is this reasoning correct or not? 
How should I determine the value of "$\varepsilon$"?
Do we need the initial CTR, 1.5%, at all?

Comment: You ought to ask yourself what "95% accuracy" might actually mean. Could it be that after the experiment is over you are absolutely sure the CTR is between $(1-0.95)\times 4\%$ and $(1+0.95)\times 4\%$? Probably not; probably it's assumed you will construct some kind of confidence interval for the estimate. But confidence intervals have *two* characteristics: their confidence level (presumably the 95%, but who knows) and *their length*. You simply haven't enough information even to know what question is being asked! Are you sure you're quoting the problem correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Yes, I've translated the problem word-for-word. It looked equally incomplete initially.
As far as I understand it, it is supposed to be this way, and I've got to come up with some plausible answer using the given conditions. The only way I've come up with is using this 95% as a substitute for the both characteristics you named (which is, of course, technically incorrect). But maybe there are more correct/plausible ways of reasoning that I'm missing?

Comment: I think your free parameter "$\epsilon$" is exactly what whuber means when saying that you also need the "length" of your confidence interval.